# Bring focus to the terminal with node.js script

Tags: node.js, macos

I have a node.js script waiting for certain event.
How do I bring focus to the terminal it is running in when the event occurs?
I'm using OS X

Comment: I think, it is nothing to do with node.js. It is mac os window management.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be mine solution to achieve this:

1) create a shell script to focus a terminal window (or grab one from the internet)
2) use [child process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) to run it from nodejs script.

Comment: But of course! I went with apple script to avoid installing new stuff.